# getting values from a POST method in expressJS

Tags: javascript, express

I'm trying to register a user in my application. This is the HTML code:

```
<form id="registration_form" action="register" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="user[name]" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="user[pass]" /><br />
        Repeat Password: <input type="password" id="password_repeat" name="user[pass]" /><br />
        Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="user[email]" /><br />
        <button type="submit" value="Register">Register</button>
        <div id="error_registration" style="color: red;">
        </div>
    </form>
```

What I do in the server is taking the values of name, pass and email.

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer(
    express.logger(),
        express.cookieParser(),
        express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' })
    )
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , schemas = require('./schemas')
  , Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

app.listen(80);
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});
```

[...]

```
app.post('/register', function (req, res) {
    registerUser(req, function(result){
         //do something
         var username = req.body.username;
    });
});
```

My question is: why username is always undefined? Am I reading it in the wrong way? How should I then?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is user not username.

Look:

..input type="text" id="username" name="**user**[name]" ..

Also you can always do console.log(req.body) to see the POST vars in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's not the problem. I tried to change the name of the variables but still I get undefined. Moreover if I try something like console.log(req.body) I just get [Object object]. I could try with some iterator on the object content but I'll get a lot of junk... [edit]: I just tried to print the junk and actually I just get an object with name `name` so I guess I discovered how to get the variables! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Btw, when you console.log something and you get [Object object] use console.log(JSON.stringify(stuff)) instead.